# How do I get all values from one position in a tuple in a pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe where several columns are filled with tuples with two values each, mixed types.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

D = [{'A':1,'B':'Test1','C':('C1',True)},\
     {'A':2,'B':'Test2','C':(77,u'orz')},\
     {'A':3,'B':'Test3','C':(u'ASDFG',[1,2,3])}]

F = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(D)

print F
```

This is the normal output:

```
    A      B                   C
0  1  Test1          (C1, True)
1  2  Test2           (77, orz)
2  3  Test3  (ASDFG, [1, 2, 3])
```

And what I want is e.g. the second value from each tuple in column C, that is an output like:

```
True, orz, [1,2,3]
```

In Numpy you can do this:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
print A[:,0]
```

Giving you:

```
[1 4 7]
```

But this doesn't work in pandas, so is there any way to do this or do I have to transform the data in a different way?

Comment: I doubt that you can do that in numpy. Your numpy example is different. For pandas, that would mean selecting the first column. And for this example you need to unpack that tuple as well. Either by iterating, or by creating another column.

Comment: With that mixed datatype, you would have an array of obj dtype and slicing won't work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer to stay in the pandas DafaFrame / Series domain:

```
F.C.apply(lambda x: x[-1])
```

Returns:

```
>>> F.C.apply(lambda x: x[-1])
0         True
1          orz
2    [1, 2, 3]
Name: C, dtype: object
```

Comment: Even better. I love those lambda expressions.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use a list comprehension and extract the second item in the tuple pair.

```
>>> [tup[1] for tup in F.C]
[True, u'orz', [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: Damn, how did I miss such an easy solution? Thanks!

Comment: You can also use F['C'] instead of F.C. I do not know if one is a better practice than the other, though.

Comment: @HolyDanna Yes you can use either.  It makes no difference in this simple example, however.  It matters if the column name has spaces, e.g. F['my column'] or if the column name is the same as an existing property or method, e.g. F['sum'] vs. F.sum.